# Artifactory configured to store binaries in two places mistakenly(?) and how to get back to one

Tags: artifactory

Have both a storage.properties and a binarystore.xml, is it possible that Artifactory is picking up both these and storing the binaries with in the Derby (as specified in the storage.properties) and in the file-system (as specified in the binarystore.xml)?

Certainly seems so based on disk usage. Would a solution be to just remove the storage.properties, restart and Artifactory would then only use the file-system?

Version 6.17.0 (Pro)

*binarystore.xml content:*

```
<config version="v1">
    <chain template="file-system"/>
    <provider type="file-system" id="file-system">
        <binariesDir>/some/path/active/data/filestore</binariesDir>
    </provider>
</config>
```

*storage.properties content:*

```
type=derby
url=jdbc:derby:{db.home};create=true
driver=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

From Artifactory version 4.6 and above, Artifactory do not use storage.properties file to get the binarystore configuration, instead it use binarystore.xml file so you can take a backup of storage.properties file and remove it and perform a restart. Also, please make sure you have correct details in db.properties file. As Artifactory will read the database configuration from db.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

These are completely two different files for two different configurations. The functionality of the *binarystore.xml*  file is to define the location where you want to store the uploaded artifacts/binaries.

Whereas the *storage.properties* defines the database the Artifactory needs to connect/use (which is by default derby). However, please be informed of the usage of *storage.properties* file has been deprecated a long time back in 4.X version of Artifactory and replaced by *db.propertiies* file.

You can rename the *storage.properties* and restart the service and it shouldn't cause any issue. **Do not remove any data** from $Artiifactory_home/data/derby - internal Derby writes all data here.